# get iframe page title from javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to get iframe src page title and then set main page title

Comment: Are the pages in same domain. If it is not that means you try to do Cross Site Scripting. You could still do that but you need to set Domain in the page you opening in iframe

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it using jQuery:

```
var title = $("#frame_id").contents().find("title").html();
$(document).find("title").html(title);
```

You can do it only when pages are on the same domain, otherwise it's useless.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the webpage is in the iframe is from the same domain as the containing page, it is impossible.

If they do have the same domain, then try the following:

```
document.title = document.getElementById("iframe").documentElement.title;
```

Comment: `contentDocument`. Except in IE6-7, where you have to fall back to the non-standard `contentWindow.document`. `documentElement` is the root html tag; the `title` property is on the HTMLDocument itself.

Answer (score 3):

Granting that iframes src and the parent document src are the same domain:

Parent document:

```
<html>
<head><title>Parent</title>
<body>
   <iframe id="f" src="someurl.html"></iframe>
   <script>
       //if the parent should set the title, here it is
       document.title = document.getElementById('f').contentWindow.document.title;
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

someurl.html:

```
<html>
<head><title>Child</title>
<body>
  <script>
       //if the child wants to set the parent title, here it is
       parent.document.title = document.title;
       //or top.document.title = document.title;

  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: iframe.contentWindow.document returns null in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can share title and location:

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/home.html?title='+document.title+'&url='+window.location+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

and then you can read the parameters on home.html page.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using event listeners on the page.  It's not particularly elegant, but the browsers I have tried it with support it (so IE9+, Firefox, Chrome).

In your main site page add the following javascript:

```
function setPageTitle(event) {
    var newPageTitle = event.data
    // your code for setting the page title and anything else you're doing
}
addEventListener('message', setPageTitle, false);
```

In the iFrame, you'll then need to have the following script:

```
var targetOrigin = "http://your.domain.com"; // needed to let the browser think the message came from your actual domain
parent.postMessage("New page title", targetOrigin); // this will trigger the message listener in the parent window
```

Comment: For more browser support use: if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", listener);
} else {
    // IE8
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
}