# Get title from IFrame document

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, title

This is my code:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <script>
        document.title = document.getElementById("main-content-iframe").contentDocument.title;
    </script>
    <iframe name="cstage" src="home.html" width="100%" height="100%" id="main-content-iframe" frameborder="0" onload="document.title=parent.frames['cframe'].document.title;">If you're seeing this message, it means IFrames are not supported; Please enable IFrames or upgrade to a compatible browser that supports IFrames.</iframe>
</div>
```

It's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: The js in the script tags is not in a document ready call, so its executing before the iframe has loaded so that part will not function correctly.

Comment: have you seen this post? might be useful [get iframe page title from javascript using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570808/get-iframe-page-title-from-javascript-using-jquery)

Comment: @PubliDesign That shows the jQuery syntax, but since his syntax is correct it won't solve the problem. His problem is timing.

Comment: So do you say hello before you dial your phone? Basically what you are doing there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to check that the iframe is loaded.

```
<div id="main-content">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <iframe name="cstage" src="home.html" width="100%" height="100%" id="main-content-iframe" frameborder="0" onload="document.title=parent.frames['cframe'].document.title;">If you're seeing this message, it means IFrames are not supported; Please enable IFrames or upgrade to a compatible browser that supports IFrames.</iframe>
<script>
    $( "iframe" ).on('load',function() {
        document.title = document.getElementById("main-content-iframe").contentDocument.title;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's hardly "useless", now is it?

Comment: @ Kalle H. Väravas ..gives an alternate approach.... sometimes it IS a solution for some.. @KenSharp .. Vote up ..'cuz the SO thought it was right too!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `document.title` of the page. When attempting to access elements inside of an iframe, you need to first get the iframe(which you did), then you can access any property of the document(the iframe) like you would normally.

## General Answer

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
<button onclick="getIframeTitle()">get iframe title</button>
```

```js
function getIframeTitle() {
  // getting our iframe
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  // logging the iframe's title
  console.log(iframe.contentWindow.document.title);
}
```

## Specific to your question

```html
<div id="main-content">
    <script>
        document.title = document.getElementById("main-content-iframe").contentDocument.document.title;
    </script>
    <iframe name="cstage" src="home.html" width="100%" height="100%" id="main-content-iframe" frameborder="0" onload="document.title=parent.frames['cframe'].document.title;">If you're seeing this message, it means IFrames are not supported; Please enable IFrames or upgrade to a compatible browser that supports IFrames.</iframe>
</div>
```

See [How TO - Get Iframe Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp) for further reading.

Answer (score -2):

Try code maybe can help you

```
HTML code:
<div id="main-content">   
    <iframe name="cstage" src="home.html" width="100%" height="100%" id="main-content-iframe" frameborder="0">If you're seeing this message, it means IFrames are not supported; Please enable IFrames or upgrade to a compatible browser that supports IFrames.</iframe>
</div> 

jQuery code:
alert($('#main-content-iframe').contents().find("title").text());
```

Note: Make sure home.html come from the same domain as your main page.