# Get title of updated iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I am uodaring an iFrame's HTLM from a text editor and now I want to get the title of the iFrame but I have been unable without getting the iFrame's content again.

```
var iFrame =  document.getElementById('myframe');
var iFrameBody;
if ( iFrame.contentDocument )
{ // FF
    iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
}
else if ( iFrame.contentWindow )
{ // IE
    iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
}
iFrameBody.innerHTML = x;

console.log(iFrameBody.title);
```

I have tried `iFrameBody.getElementsByTagName('title')`

`console.log(iFrameBody);` gives:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Add your heading tag below-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not a property of `<html>` element...it's property of document

Answer (score 0):

This does the job

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.title
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471370/get-title-from-iframe-document)

Comment: yes that does work, is there a way to get it from iFrameBody object rather that getting the content of the iframe again?

Comment: @KeithPower None that I know off, but why would you want to do it that way?