# How do I detect the title of an embedded webpage in html?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, page-title

I am creating an html program that loads other webpages inside an `iframe`. I want to be able to read the title of the document that is being viewed. Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471370/get-title-from-iframe-document