# Recieve IFrames favicon and title and display on browser tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would love to know how in Javascript to receive and display iFrames title and favicon on the browser tab title.

Comment: Good luck with your learning. 
If you want someone here to help you, you need to work on a code first and post specific question with code snippet and errors.

Comment: Generally speaking, if the iFrames are pointed at domains you do not control, this is data you will not have access to (as far as the favicon, since that generally comes from the iFrame document, which is basically not accessible). Otherwise, this is how you get the title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471370/get-title-from-iframe-document