# how to set window title in a webpage

Tags: javascript, nvda

is there any possible way to set document window title.I've a webpage, in that webpage we are loading Iframe(which is from another project).By default it is taking current webpage title.how can I override the title with with current Iframe page title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get iframe page title from javascript using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570808/get-iframe-page-title-from-javascript-using-jquery)

Comment: Duplicate question that's already been answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1570900/3066711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Get the title for the iframe in whatever manner works best for you and then set the document title using:

```
document.title = "New Title"
```

If you don't know how to get the iframe title, try something along these lines:

```
document.title = document.getElementById("main-content-iframe").contentDocument.title;
```