# How to fetch the loaded iframe title element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I'm trying to write a script to have a dynamic title for my iframe element instead of hard-coding a title attribute. So I want to grab the the src of the iframe and load that object then fetch the title element of that object. I tried using iframe.contentDocument but I am getting the cross-domain security error.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1570900/4965214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, you cannot access the content of another domain for security reasons (like that). A way around this for your use case would be to load the site of the `iframe` with ajax and read the title from the response.
Since the title-tag is not part of the document (=body) you can't get it with `$('title', dom)` or `dom.find('title')`. But you can retrieve it like in the example below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var url = $('iframe').prop('src');
                $.get(url)
                    .done(function(html){
                        var dom = $(html);
                        var title = dom
                            .filter(function(i,d){ 
                                return d.tagName == 'TITLE'; 
                            })
                            .text();
                        $('h1 span').text(title);
                    })
                ;
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Title: <span></span></h1>
            <iframe src="http://www.golem.de" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;" />
        </body>
    </html>
```